# iOS 13 Navbar Strange Behavior

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, tableview, navbar

I’m brand new to this, taught myself Swift for the purpose of creating this one app. I’d nearly finished when I updated to iOS 13, which introduced a whole slew of new issues. So I’m working my way through them one by one, trying to figure them out as best I can, but here are two I was hoping maybe someone here could. Thanks!

[**Take a look at this screen capture video.**](https://youtu.be/5xLtJM36-wk)

I have a tableview with a searchcontroller and searchbar. The hot pink is a view behind it that I have placed there to make it easier to see the problem (I’ve also set it to slow motion).

**1)  As soon as I select a cell in VC-1 and begin the push to VC-2, the background of my searchcontroller becomes transparent, as does the space above the navbar. What’s going on here?  And when I push back, the opposite happens—a bar of black equal in height to the searchcontroller on VC-1 abruptly appears over my content of VC-2 as it transitions away.**

**2)  Interestingly, when the searchbar is active (and shifts to the top automatically), the clear/pink space above the navbar of VC-1 is no longer a problem. However, a sliver of that clear/pink space appears beneath the navbar as the transition takes place.**

**3)  When I transition back to VC-1 from VC-2 with the searchbar active, the navbar appears to overlap the tableview. Once the transition finishes, it abruptly drops down.**

The whole sequence, which was smooth, has become quite ugly.  Any brave coders see a solution I’m overlooking? I have `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` for both view controllers.

Comment: Have you ran the app on a physical device or just the simulator?

Comment: Both, same result. Thanks for asking, though!